# Instead of triggers in PostgreSQL, how can I stop repeating column names?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a simple table inheritance hierarchy from my entity relationship model in PostgreSQL.

For this, I have created the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE base (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(40),
    test integer
);

CREATE TABLE sub (
    id integer REFERENCES base(id) PRIMARY KEY,
    count integer
);
```

Now, since how the inheritance is solved on the DB does not need to concern the application, I also created a view that the application will access. All operations from the application should be performed on the view, and as such, I also need an `instead of` trigger to perform updates, inserts and deletes. The view definition and the trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW sub_view AS
    SELECT s.count, b.title, b.test, b.id FROM sub s 
    JOIN base b ON b.id = s.id;

--TRIGGER
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION instead_of_f()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO base(id, title, test) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.title, NEW.test);
        INSERT INTO sub(id, test) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.test);
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        UPDATE base SET title = NEW.title, test = NEW.test WHERE id = OLD.id;
        UPDATE sub SET count = NEW.count WHERE id = OLD.id;
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        DELETE FROM sub WHERE id = OLD.id;
        DELETE FROM base WHERE id = OLD.id;
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER instead_of_dml_trig
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON
      sub_view FOR EACH ROW 
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE instead_of_f();
```

This basically works fine, but it is tedious and not very maintainable to have to repeat all the column names over and over again. Ideally, I would like to write something like this for the view instead:

```
CREATE VIEW sub_view AS
   SELECT * FROM sub s JOIN base b ON b.id = s.id;
```

And instead of the insert statements in the trigger:

```
INSERT INTO base VALUES NEW.*;
INSERT INTO sub VALUES NEW.*;
```

Is this somehow possible? I couldn't find anything similar, except for audit triggers, and those just saved the `NEW` and `OLD` records as a string. In this contrived example it would be easy enough to add new columns or delete them as the `base`/`sub` tables change, but as soon as there are a few more sub tables and more columns this becomes practically unmaintainable.

Comment: Why don't you use PostgreSQL's native [TABLE inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-inherit.html)? You could have all your sub tables to inherit from the base one, and write the queries referring directly to them, no VIEWS nor TRIGGERS needed.

Comment: Because the documentation says it doesn't support inheriting foreign keys or primary keys, one of the most important aspects I would need.

Comment: You could probably write a trigger that does this with dynamic SQL. You'd use queries against the `information_schema` to find out which columns are part of which tables, and `EXECUTE format(...) USING (...)` to prepare the SQL. Dynamic access to columns from `NEW` is possible, but awkward. Overall it'll be slow and painful, but it'll work. Really, the best way to do this would be to implement the trigger in C where you could use the PostgreSQL relcache, `heap_form_tuple`, etc, but that's pretty advanced.

Comment: Or, you could still use table inheritance: create a *sub_table generation* function which executes some dynamic sql to generate the sub tables and define the PRIMARY and FOREIGN keys needed (those which are required by the base_table). Then you can have some triggers that take care of the UNIQUE-ness required across sub and base tables. That would be trivial to implement since the columns depend on the base table only and quite performing as well, since it will query against indexes in both tables. The trigger will be attached to the sub table by that *sub_table_generation* function too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Craig suggested, I ended up solving it in my application directly, not on the database. My application knows all the relevant columns from the views, as well as the base types, so it ended up being easier to just create the trigger and the view in the migrations there.